# How to multiply the number of two labels in C#

Tags: c#, string, integer, label

so i have 2 labels. one of them is a fixed number and doesn't change but the other one changes every 5 seconds. Now i want to multiply them automatically and show them in another label as Results.

what should i do? what am i doing wrong?

i tried this code but it says "operator * cannot be applied to string and string".

```
label1.Text = BTC_A.Text * BTCPrice_Label.Text;
```

then i tried

```
double txt1 = Convert.ToDouble(BTC_A.Text);
            double txt2 = Convert.ToDouble(BTCPrice_Label.Text);

            double sum = txt1 * txt2;

            label1.Text = sum.ToString();
```

but it says "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: It's easier if you use _data binding_

Comment: @MickyD how can i do that?!

Comment: `label1.Text = double.Parse(BTC_A.Text) * double.Parse(BTCPrice_Label.Text);`

Comment: @Gusman i tried it but it said "cannot implicitly convert double to string" then i tried this label1.Text = (double.Parse(BTC_A.Text) * double.Parse(BTCPrice_Label.Text)).ToString(); and i got 'Input string was not in a correct format.' error

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" means that the text in one of the two controls is not convertible to double. What exactly is the content of these controls? Note that Convert.ToDouble is culture-sensitive, so depending on your current culture it would expect the decimal separator either as '.' or as ','

Comment: @KlausGütter thank you man. the problem was caused by a dollar sign!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was a dollar sign ( $ ) that i put before the numbers.

i just deleted the sign and this is what the code looks like now:

```
double AA;
           if (!double.TryParse(BTC_A.Text, out AA))
           {
                MessageBox.Show($"Unable to convert the BTC_A \"{BTC_A.Text}\" to a floating point number");
                return;
           }
           double btcA;
           if (!double.TryParse(BTCPrice_Label.Text, out btcA))
           {
                MessageBox.Show($"Unable to convert the price \"{BTCPrice_Label.Text}\" to a floating point number");
                return;
           }
           label1.Text = (AA * btcA).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it through step by step.

You have labels with a `Text` property. That property is of type `string`. C# is a strongly typed language: strings can not be multiplied like that. In the end, a label can be empty, or the user could input any random string. What would be the result of `"foo" * "bar"`?

Also, when you do have a `double` as a result of some multiplication, you want to show it to the user in another `label.Text`. Here you have the inverse issue: C#/.Net does not convert the variable of type `double` implicitly to a string.

So you will have to

- check if the strings entered by the user is actually a valid double
- if they are, convert those strings to `double` and multiply them
- convert the result to a string, and assign it to the labels `Text` property
- if the strings are not valid numbers, leave the label empty, or show some other message

The logic to achieve this would be something like this:

```
var validPrice = int.TryParse(BTCPrice_Label.Text, out double price);
var validAmount = int.TryParse(BTCA_Label.Text, out double amount);
if (validPrice && validAmount)
{
    var result = price * amount;
    label1.Text = result.ToString();
}
else
{
    label1.Text = "something is wrong";
}
```